# Partial string exact matching

Tags: r, data-manipulation, grepl

I have searched a lot but was not able to find a solution... I think for many of you this is an easy one... but not for me.

```
 df <- data.frame(site = c("11", " 4 , 111", "3,1 ", "4,11111 "))
> df
      site
1       11
2  4 , 111
3     3,1 
4 4,11111
```

I have a column in which multiple site codes might be separated by a comma (not the random spaces that might occur). I am trying to find rows that match a string site numbers of interest.

The results of searching for rows in which the site is either 11 or 3 'c(1,3)' matches should thus return:

```
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

I can't seem to get this out... I guess the answer would include

```
temp <- strsplit(df$site, ",")
```

, but the I can't seem to understand how to apply functions on lists after that step... I'd do a

```
grepl(c("^11$", "^3$"), temp)
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: What do the 1s and 0s represent?  Are they simply  "yes" and "no" or are they supposed to give the number of matches in each string?

Comment: A somewhat leisurely version: `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% group_by(row = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(site, sep = ',', convert = TRUE) %>% summarise(result = as.integer(any(site == 11 | site == 3)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for exact match rather than pattern match, you can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(site = c("11", " 4 , 111", "3,1 ", "4,11111 "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.integer(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$site, split=","), function(x) any(x == 3 | x == 11))))

[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: You could do a bit of code-squishing too `sapply(strsplit(df$site, split=","), function(x) any(x %in% c(3,11)))`

Comment: These edits made it work completely: sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$site), split=","), function(x) any(as.numeric(x) %in% c(11,1))). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using sapply

```
as.integer(sapply(df$site,function(x)grepl("^11|^3",x)))

[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Searching for '1' only results in 1 0 0 0, which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

We can just do a `grep`

```
+(grepl("\\b(3|11)\\b", df$site))
#[1] 1 0 1 0
```